# Discord.js Reaction Collector is doing nothing

Tags: discord.js

```
     const newUserEmbed = await message.reply({ embeds: [reportEmbed]});
        console.log(`User Report Created (reportCreated = true)`);

        try {
            await newUserEmbed.react("");
            await newUserEmbed.react("❌");
            await newUserEmbed.react("❓");
        } catch (err) {
          message.channel.send('`ERROR: Reactions Error`');
          throw err;
        };

        const collector = newUserEmbed.createReactionCollector(
          (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"),
          { dispose: true }
        );

        collector.on('collect', (message, reaction, user) => {
            console.log('Collecting Reactions for User Report (collectorRun = true)');
            switch (reaction.emoji.name){
                case "":
                  newUserEmbed.delete();
                  message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been marked as completed.`);
                  break;
                case "❌":
                  newUserEmbed.delete();
                  message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been declined.`);
                  break;
                case "❓":
                  newUserEmbed.delete();
                  message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been marked as inconclusive.`);
                  break;
            }
        });
```

I am trying to create a command that allows a user to report a user easily. All of the code works (such as the embed, the buttons, adding the reactions), EXCEPT for the reaction collector. The bot is able to react to the message, but click on the reactions does nothing. I have no idea why this is happening, after checking for typos, or other small issues.

I have read through similar questions on Stack Overflow, but the answers do not seem to help in my case.

Comment: Are you using v12 or v13? If v13, have you declared intents for `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` ?

Comment: I am using v13, and I have declared that intent.

Comment: Update: When I added the intent, it began to throw an error which stated 

"TypeErr: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
Which it was referring to this line of code:

```switch (reaction.emoji.name){```

Comment: `console.log(reaction.emoji)` if I remember right there is different values in guild emojis and unicode ones.

Comment: Ok, now ```console.log('Collecting Reactions for User Report (collectorRun = true)');``` does what it should. However, when I click on a reaction, it just does the same console.log instead of doing what I declared in my switch.